# How to check whether a list index is present or not

Tags: python, list

I have the following list

```
a = ['a','c','d']
```

I need to check whether the list index 4(or any index) is present on the list or not. Is there a method similar to php [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) in python for this(without using exception handling)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `len()` to check whether the Index is present or not.

As `len(list)` returns something like `last_index+1`:

```
In [18]: a = ['a','c','d']

In [19]: len(a)-1 > 4  #or len(a)>4
Out[19]: False

In [20]: len(a)-1 > 2
Out[20]: True
```

Comment: bit explanation will be helpful to OP :) ..I mean list indexes are continue..unlike dict

Answer (score 6):

```
if len(a) > 4:
    # list contains fourth element, a[4]
```

or

```
try:
    a[4] # do something with a[4]
except IndexError:
    print "there is no element a[4]"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can always check:

```
if index < len(a):
    # do stuff
```