# Best way to check if a list has value at a given index

Tags: python

Now I do like this, to check if my list l has index idx:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

idx = 5

try:
    value = l[idx]
except IndexError:
    value = None 

print(value) 
# gives None
```

Is there some function like: l.hasindex(idx) or something else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check whether a list index is present or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334586/how-to-check-whether-a-list-index-is-present-or-not)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see if the absolute value of the index less than the length.  If so, then the list has the index.  You do need to special case for negative indices.  `-len(lst)` is valid ...

```
def hasindex(lst, idx):
    ln = len(lst)
    return (abs(idx) < ln) or (idx == -ln)
```

Comment: @MartinKonecny -- I didn't initially.  It took me a minute or two to realize my error :).  It's a shame too because of needing to special case `-len(lst)`... Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is none. You can easly write it yourself:

```
get_value_at_index = lambda l, i:  l[idx] if idx < len(l) else None

value = get_value_at_index(l, idx)
```